# How do I ignore files in node.js which are required by another file or component

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

The following can ignore or perform some modification of the files imported e.g. in my index.js

```
require.extensions['.js'] = function(file) {
    console.log(file.id)
    return;
};
```

However I don't really want to ignore these files in the index.js I want to ignore files imported in subsequent files/Components

```
require.extensions['.js'] = function(file) {
    console.log(file.id)
    return;
};

require('babel-register')

require('./components/Test.spec.js');
```

For instance this logs the following and returns

```
/Users/me/myapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js
/Users/me/myapp/tests/components/Test.spec.js
```

Really what I want is for it to ignore any included files of a particular type in the `Test.spec.js` file

I know of the option of specifying ignore in babel require however this just ignores them being transpiled, so is not really what I want. Basically I want a specific file type, e.g. `.jsx` to not be compiled, or possibly I can override this require and return another function.

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want to ignore any svg files which are included in my react components which I am testing with tape and enzyme. Similar to how [css-modules-require-hook](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook) requires css files at runtime

Comment: Still unclear. You want to ignore them at test time or at production build time?

Answer (score 0):

This hack should work:

```
ignore = [];
var original_require = require;
require = function(file){
    if(ignore.indexOf(file)!=-1) return original_require(file);
};
```

Just paste this code before any require.
And now you can do this:

File a.js:

```
console.log('I\'m a');    
ignore.push('./c');
require('./b');
```

File b.js:

```
console.log('I\'m b');
require('./c');
```

File c.js:

```
console.log('I\'m c');
```

The result will be:

```
I'm a
I'm b
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work require seems to be redefined in every file